# Strange behaviour that R retains last variable in list loop?

Tags: r, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

When I make a loop to wrap functions in a list, the last function in the input list is always used for all wrapping call.

```
wrapper <- function(f)function()f()
fs <- list(f = function()"call f", g = function()"call g")
ws <- list()
for(n in names(fs))
    ws[[n]] <- wrapper(fs[[n]])
ws$f()
[1] "call g"
```

I expected `"call f"` in the above code, but it returned `"call g"` in fact.

Could anyone explain me why this happened?

What is the sign, or in which situation I have to force evaluation to avoid the similar

Thank you very much

Comment: I suspect lazy evaluation of the culprit. Try using `force(n)` in your loop before the code you have now.

Comment: Curiously, `ws <- lapply(fs, wrapper); ws$f()` works

Comment: @alistaire AFAIK, `lapply` does `force` on each element of the list. While my loop does not

Comment: @Dason: `force(n)` in the loop does **not** work. `force(f)` in `wrapper` works, instead

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out my own answer

There are 2 reasons why this happens: `for` loop does not have its own environment and `wrapper` does lazily evaluate its parameter `f`.

For the first reason: `for` loop uses the global environment

For the latter reason: changing `wrapper` to `function(f){force(f); function()f()}` leads to my expected result in the question.

Detailed explanation:

The loop in the question is interpreted into

```
for(n in names(fs)){
  tmp <- fs[[n]]
  ws[[n]] <- wrapper(tmp)
}
```

Because `wrapper` does lazily evaluate parameter `f`, it keeps `f` in its execution environment but does not keep its value. Instead, it memorizes how-to-evaluate `f` when need. In other word, it memorizes the pair `(<environment: R_GlobalEnv>, "tmp")`.

Checking out the following code clears everything I said.

```
tmp <- f
wf <- wrapper(tmp)
tmp <- g
wf()
[1] "call g"
```

but

```
tmp <- f
wf <- wrapper(tmp)
wf()
[1] "call f"
tmp <- g
wf()
[1] "call f"
```

The latter code printed `"call f"` in the second call because `f` is evaluated and stored in `wrapper`'s environment and there is no need to evaluated again (to become `g`)