# Plotting densities calculated in Julia with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to create a map with a density layer on top using the `geom_hdr()` function from the [ggdensity](https://github.com/jamesotto852/ggdensity) package. The data to create this density layer is large (27 million rows), and attempting to plot fails with `vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`.

I have considered using Julia's [KernelDensity.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/KernelDensity.jl) and passing the results to `geom_hdr`, but my understanding of ggplot internals is too poor to achieve that (or to know if it is achievable).

I could create the entire plot in Julia, but since parts of the project already use maps created with ggplot, it would be great to keep the visuals as similar as possible.

Here goes a MWE of the issue in R:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdensity)

ggplot() + geom_hdr(aes(x = rnorm(2e7), y = rnorm(2e7)))
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_hdr()`
# Caused by error:
# ! vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

And the KDE I calculated using Julia, but did not know how to use for plotting with ggplot:

```
using KernelDensity

n = Int64(2e7)
a, b = randn(n), randn(n)
kde((a,b))
```

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll notice the difference in the density if you use a  random selection of 10% of the data.

Comment: Alternatively, you could specify a custom `method_julia()` function for the `method` argument to `geom_hdr`.  It should return a matrix of density values.  See `vignette("method", "ggdensity")` for details.

Comment: Thank you for your response! We had experimented with the 10% solution you suggested before already. Sadly, since some areas are quite sparse while others are super dense, the subsamples left us without the low density areas in almost all iterations.

Specifying a custom method sounds great, I will look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a `method_julia()` thanks to user2554330's suggestion.

```
library(JuliaCall)

method_julia <- function(h = NULL, adjust = c(1, 1)) {
    force(h)
    force(adjust)
    julia_setup()
    julia_command("using KernelDensity")
    function(data, n, rangex, rangey) {
        if (is.null(h)) {
            h <- c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(data$x), MASS::bandwidth.nrd(data$y))
        }
        h <- h * adjust
        julia_assign("data", data)
        julia_assign("h", h)
        julia_assign("n", as.integer(n))
        julia_assign("rangex", rangex)
        julia_assign("rangey", rangey)
        julia_command("kdeout = kde((data.x, data.y); npoints=(n,n), boundary=((rangex[1], rangex[2]), (rangey[1], rangey[2])), bandwidth=(h[1],h[2]))")
        x <- julia_eval("kdeout.x")
        y <- julia_eval("kdeout.y")
        fhat <- julia_eval("kdeout.density")
        df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
        df$fhat <- as.vector(fhat)
        df
    }
}
```

It plots the large data from the MWE above without error:

```
library(ggdensity)

ggplot() + 
    geom_hdr(aes(x = rnorm(2e7), y = rnorm(2e7)), method = method_julia())
```

I am happy to receive feedback if the function above could be improved!

Comment: My only suggestion would be to add `force(h)` to `method_julia()` before building the function that uses it (and `force(adjust)` too, if you use that).  I think you don't need to do this with the code you showed, but you would get unexpected results in some obscure cases, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949941/2554330.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the initial help once again!